# Core Data context save: Is code run sequentially?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

My method saveNote uses selectedNote in its core data context save operation. Is it possible that the second line of code will run before the saveNote method finishes?

```
    [self saveNote];
    selectedNote = [[self.editNoteViewControllerDelegate selectPreviousNote] initArrays];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course no. If you are using selectedNote in the method 'saveNote', all that method is finished before the second line of your code is executed. That is, you are calling a method and not launching a new thread or postponing the action.